# Convert Android BROWSABLE Uri to SAF Uri

Tags: android, storage, uri

is-it possible to convert `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE` Uri :

> content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file%3A%2F%2F%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDocuments%2Ftest.txt

to `Storage Access Framework` Uri :

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments%2Ftest.txt

Thanks

Comment: What is a browseble uri? And where did you get it from?

Comment: You see that the provider serves from path: `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/test.txt` ?

Comment: As you know how both content schemes look like you could easily do such a conversion yourself. But why would you? You probably would not have access to that file using the new content provider as that provider did not give permission for it to you.

Comment: It's to access to the directory using SAF, the problem is for the SD card, is not content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary... ?

Comment: You are not mentioning an sd card in your post. Write a post that is to the point please.

Comment: An USB key return for browsable Uri "content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/1/file%3A%2F%2F%2Fmnt%2Fmedia_rw%2F76CB-4FB1%2Ftest.txt" and saf Uri is "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/76CB-4FB1%3Atest.txt", and google drive, smb too...

Comment: `Write a post that is to the point please.` That was asked. Why did you use a comment to write a post? Write a good post then you can remove that comment. It makes no fun to read your problem in this way. Take some effort please.

Comment: It's not possible, thanks. You don't know "BROWSABLE intent" : the file type element allows you to declare the file types with which an application can be associated.